# PHP / AJAX will only submit results of form once. First click works, second is blank

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm getting some very odd behavior and I can't figure it out.

I've modified a piece of code from Bright Cherry [http://bit.ly/fmhcbu] and I'm basically just trying to change the value of a mySQL row from 0 to 1 or vice versa and refresh the results onscreen.

[VIEW PAGE HERE](http://www.brianrhea.com/ai_groups.php)

When you click the submit button, the record is updated in the database and the page auto refreshes correctly. But, when you click a second button, nothing happens.

Has anyone run in to this issue before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your backend PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to re-run the jQuery ajaxForm code after **each** reload.

update the  code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeAjaxForm(){
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
      target: '#showdata',
      success: function() {
        $('#showdata').fadeIn('slow');
        makeAjaxForm();
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    makeAjaxForm();
  });
  </script>
```